# I cloned repository from GitHub but there are missing commits on my local cloned repository

Tags: git, csv, repository, clone, commit

There is a small project on GitHub, my friend used to make set of commits and push them several days ago. Today I cloned this repository with IntelliJ IDEA but I'm not able to see changes that my friend made (commits). How do I need to clone repository to get with commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned commits your friend made, then there will be a commit sha-1.
You can ask your friend for the latest commit sha-1, the execute command
`git switch -c temp-20200923-001 {commmit sha-1}`
If the above command execute failed, then your friend might forgot to push his code to git server.
If the above command execute successfully, you will get what you want on a new branch called temp-20200923-001

Answer (score 0):

When you do a standard `git clone` you will have all the branches and objects from that remote. From here on you'll have to `git fetch origin` to get updates. There are two options here:

1. He didn't push those changes
2. You're looking at the wrong branch

Try calling:

```
$ git branch -r
```

To see an overview of all the remote branches. Maybe that'll give you enough of a hint.